# What is representation in optical character recognition?

Tags: ocr, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I am learning OCR and reading this book [https://www.amazon.com/Character-Recognition-Different-Languages-Computing/dp/3319502514](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319502514)

The authors define 8 processes to implement OCR that follow one by one (2 after 1, 3 after 2 etc):

1. Optical scanning
2. Location segmentation
3. Pre-processing
4. Segmentation
5. Representation
6. Feature extraction
7. Recognition
8. Post-processing

This is what they write about representation (#5)

> The fifth OCR component is representation. The image representation
>   plays one of the most important roles in any recognition system. In
>   the simplest case, gray level or binary images are fed to a
>   recognizer. However, in most of the recognition systems in order to
>   avoid extra complexity and to increase the accuracy of the algorithms,
>   a more compact and characteristic representation is required. For this
>   purpose, a set of features is extracted for each class that helps
>   distinguish it from other classes while remaining invariant to
>   characteristic differences within the class.The character image 
>   representation methods are generally categorized into three major
>   groups: (a) global transformation and series expansion (b) statistical
>   representation and (c) geometrical and topological representation.

This is what they write about feature extraction (#6)

> The sixth OCR component is feature extraction. The objective of
>   feature extraction is to capture essential characteristics of symbols.
>   Feature extraction is accepted as one of the most difficult problems
>   of pattern recognition. The most straight forward way of describing
>   character is by actual raster image. Another approach is to extract
>   certain features that characterize symbols but leaves the unimportant
>   attributes. The techniques for extraction of such features are divided
>   into three groups’ viz. (a) distribution of points (b) transformations
>   and series expansions and (c) structural analysis.

I am totally confused. I don't understand what is representation. As I understand after segmentation we must take from image some features, for example topological structure like Freeman chain code and must match to some saved at the learning stage model - i.e. to do recognition. By other words - segmentation - feature extraction - recognition.  I don't understand what must be done on representation stage. Please, explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation component takes the raster image produced by segmentation and converts it into a simpler format (a "representation") that preserves the characteristic properties of classes. This is in order to reduce the complexity of the recognition process later on. The Freeman chain code you mention is one such representation.

Some (most?) authors conflate representation and feature extraction into a single step, but the authors of your book have chosen to treat them separately. Changing the representation isn't mandatory, but doing so reduces the complexity, and so increases the accuracy, of the training and recognition steps.

It is from this simpler representation that features are extracted in the feature extraction step. Which features are extracted will depend upon the representation chosen. This paper - [Feature Extraction Methods for Character Recognition - A Survey](http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~dinstein/stip2002/FeatureExtractionReviewTrierJainTaxt95.pdf) - describes 11 different feature extraction methods that can be applied to 4 different representations.

The extracted features are what are passed to the trainer or recognizer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain then what is done on feature extraction step? Because in most of the books workflow is such : ... segmentation - feature extraction - recognition. So representation is optional. But from your answer it means that representation is always required.

Comment: Representation is not always required, and some authors consider representation to be part of feature extraction. I have updated my answer.